# Link Excel worksheets to each other so that changes in one are mapped to the other

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a stock portfolio that I have subdivided into three thematic categories.  Every month I update  each of these categories to reflect new positions added by copying the sheets from the previous months, and manually adding all the new positions and the corresponding information.

The problem is that when I add positions to one sheet, I add a row and insert new information about that position (price, date purchased, etc.).   This obviously shifts all the cells down one, so that the other thematic sheets no longer have the same row number for the corresponding stock ticker as the newly updated sheet.  As a result, I have to manually add rows in the same position to each thematic sheet in order to preserve row number continuity.

Is there a way to somehow link sheets, so that adding a row in one area, adds a row in a corresponding area in the other two sheets, along with corresponding column information?

Comment: if the sheets are in the exact same layout then you can do that by selecting all three sheets at once and then inserting the row, otherwise the answer is yes, but you will need some means of mapping the relevant sections to each other.

Comment: They're not the same format, unfortunately.  Do you have any idea how mapping would work?